# Google Places Autocomplete auth inconsistency: "This API project is not authorized to use this API."

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places Autocomplete API in two spots in my app, but it's sharing the same script and API_KEY.  In one location, the places autocomplete works fine, but in the other it fails silently except for the return value found in the "AutocompletionService.GetPredictions" request in the network tab:

```
/**/_xdc_._6bvokq && _xdc_._6bvokq( [3, null, null,…] )
0: 3
1: null
2: null
3: "This API project is not authorized to use this API. Please ensure this API is activated in the Google Developers Console: https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/places_backend?project=_ For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

I have "enabled" the places web api as well as the maps javascript api in my google developer api console.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: @steven-harlow I have the same error and I use the same key on different subdomains..; one works, the other not... any progress ?

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced this problem as well and solved it by enabling the Geolocation and Geocoding web services. Depending on location these are queried as well. After enabling these services in the api the problem was solved for me. Hope the same works for you.